# Error on calling stored procedure on Oracle 10g server

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I call my stored procedure from C# and I get the following exception:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MY_PROC'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MY_PROC'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

As my procedure has 57 arguments it is not easy to know where is really the problem.
Is there a way to have a more detailed message ?

Note : However arguments type and number seem to match !

Here are my stored procedure arguments:

```
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(8,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(4,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(3,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(2,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(4,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(4,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(8,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(7,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(1 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(15,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(5,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(5,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(5,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(11 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(2,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(2 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(17 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(12,5),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(9,2),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(3,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(9,2),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(2 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(3 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(3,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(7,2),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(3,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(9,2), 
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(9,2),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(10,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(49 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(1 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(1 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(6 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  CHAR(1 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(9,2),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(13 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(2,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  DATE,
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
Var_PE_...  IN  NUMBER(2,0),
Var_PE_...  IN  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),

Var_PS...   OUT VARCHAR2,
Var_PS...   OUT VARCHAR2
```

And here is my call to this procedure from c#:

```
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Double,     0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Date,       0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.Int32,      0, "PE_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateInputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 0, "PE_..."));

l_Params.Add(CreateOutputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 2000, "PS_..."));
l_Params.Add(CreateOutputDbParameter(DbType.AnsiString, 2000, "PS_..."));

ExecuteStoreProcedure("MY_PROC", l_Params);
```

Home code for creating parameters:

```
    public DbParameter CreateInputDbParameter(DbType typeParam, int sizeparam,
        string nameParam, object valueParam)
    {
        DbParameter DbParam = Parameter;
        DbParam.DbType = typeParam;
        DbParam.Size = sizeparam;
        DbParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        DbParam.ParameterName = nameParam;
        if (valueParam == null)
        {
            DbParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            DbParam.Value = valueParam;
        }
        return DbParam;
    }

    public DbParameter CreateOutputDbParameter(DbType typeParam, int sizeparam, string nameParam)
    {
        DbParameter DbParam = Parameter;
        DbParam.DbType = typeParam;
        DbParam.Size = sizeparam;
        DbParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        DbParam.ParameterName = nameParam;
        return DbParam;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code for `CreateOutputDbParameter` and `CreateInputDbParameter`?

Comment: you are not create new `DbParameter DbParam = new DbParameter();` but assign `Parameter`, any reason ?

Comment: It looks like the version of CreateInputDbParameter you posted takes 4 parameters, but all the calls shown only supply 3. Is there another version of CreateInputDbParameter which only accepts 3 parameters? Also, it looks like the `nameParam` argument values passed to CreateInputDbParam and CreateOutputDbParam match the actual names of the parameters as defined in the procedure, and should thus be `'Var_PE...'`, etc.

Comment: @BobJarvis I cut lines, to have a readable code but in real code, I provide full arguments. Parameters names are not important, only their order is used.

Comment: @Damith `Parameter` is a getter on `Command.CreateParameter()`

Comment: 57 arguments? Is this a Heinz Ketchup thing?

Comment: @Glenn Sadly, it is a real life use case :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parameter direction as ParameterDirection.Output if it is output

```
OracleParameter test= 
    new OracleParameter("testparameter", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
test.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(test);
```

if it is input set it as ParameterDirection.Input

Check size of the parameters, you are not giving size when declare it. And also the type of parameter also important. for example you have `NUMBER(15,0)` mapped with `DbType.Int32`, `NUMBER(3,0)` mapped with `DbType.Double`

### EDIT

You are trying  to connect oracle using ADO.NET base classes, you know that even `System.Data.OracleClient` also deprecated.

> The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated. The types are
>   supported in version 4 of the .NET Framework but will be removed in a
>   future release. Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle
>   provider.

You better to use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) and most of these errors will be solved.

Comment: `ParameterDirection` is set when parameter is created using `CreateInputDbParameter` or `CreateOutputDbParameter`.

Comment: Sorry, but I still ese Oracle 10 and .NET 3.5 . This way to code works with some other procedure in the same program but this one is to hard to fix.